Compression/archive that can add files without extracting/recompressing
In Windows,
is there a compression format (archive format),
specialized for adding some new small numbers of files,
to already existing compressed file,
without extracting and re-compressing
the already existing compressed file ?
So that it takes very little time even if the exiting compressed file is very large.
I think .vhd can be an answer. Is there anything else ?

You do understand that virtual HDD isn't compressed; it also will have as much physical space as you have allocated when it's created. It can be expanded, but again you would need additional space on the storage media to support that.

I think zip can do this - per the Linux (command line) man page - " --grow
Grow (append to) the specified zip archive, instead of creating a new one. If this operation fails, zip attempts to restore the archive to its original state. If the restoration fails, the archive might  become  cor‐
rupted. This option is ignored when there's no existing archive or when at least one archive member must be updated or deleted.
"

I'm guessing that you already tried .zip? If not, you can open a .zip file as though it is a folder and drop new files in. I don't believe it recompresses the existing files in the archive.
